# Compare multiple row values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare for each row, values of A with the other columns

The problem is more complex but i tried to simplify it in this table:

```
     A    B    C  D
0  1.3  1.0  1.1  1
1  2.5  2.9  2.6  3
2  3.1  3.0  3.2  2
```

The result should look like this:

Here in index 0: 1.3 is larger than the values in B,C and D, then we return 1, otherwise it is 0

```
     A    B    C  D  result
0  1.3  1.0  1.1  1       1
1  2.5  2.9  2.6  3       0
2  3.1  3.0  3.2  2       0
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5):

Use `assign` to create new column
Use `df.le(df.A, 0)` to compare column `'A'` to all other columns
Use `all(1)` to find where `True` for all columns
Use `astype(int)` to make it `1` or `0`

```
df.assign(result=df.lt(df.A, 0).all(1).astype(int))

     A    B    C  D  result
0  1.3  1.0  1.1  1       1
1  2.5  2.9  2.6  3       0
2  3.1  3.0  3.2  2       0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html) or [`le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.le.html) for compare, then [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) or [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) for get at least one `True` or `all` Trues and last cast boolean mask to `int`:

```
df['result'] = (~df[['B','C','D']].gt(df.A, axis=0).any(1)).astype(int)
print (df)
     A    B    C  D  result
0  1.3  1.0  1.1  1       1
1  2.5  2.9  2.6  3       0
2  3.1  3.0  3.2  2       0
```

Another solution:

```
df['result'] = df[['B','C','D']].le(df.A, axis=0).all(1).astype(int)
print (df)
     A    B    C  D  result
0  1.3  1.0  1.1  1       1
1  2.5  2.9  2.6  3       0
2  3.1  3.0  3.2  2       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [idxmax](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
df['result'] = (df.idxmax(axis=1)== 'A').astype(int)
```

Output:

```
    A    B    C  D  result
0  1.3  1.0  1.1  1       1
1  2.5  2.9  2.6  3       0
2  3.1  3.0  3.2  2       0
```

Answer (score 0):

if you know the column names do:

```
df['results']=(df.loc[:,'A']>df.loc[:,'B':'D'].max(axis=1)).astype(int)
```

if you know want to work with columns order you can do:

```
df['results']=(df.iloc[:,0]>df.iloc[:,1:].max(axis=1)).astype(int)
```

on your example those will give the same output.
the "astype(int)" at the end converts the boolean value to 0/1.